# Google SitesApp.getActiveSite() unacceptable behavior

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to search through the current active site with Google Sites and created a custom search. The first thing I need to do is connect with the current active site see the code mentioned below. For debugging purposes I've added some timers.

```
Logger.log('---- line 289 (try to connect current active site): ' + (new Date().getTime()-startGetResultFromSiteTimer)/1000 + ' seconds');
var site = SitesApp.getActiveSite();
Logger.log('---- line 300 (connected current active site): ' + (new Date().getTime()-startGetResultFromSiteTimer)/1000 + ' seconds');
```

Sometimes it works perfectly and a request later I get this exception:

```
Exception: Servicefout: SitesApp: Internal Error
```

Very unreliable behavior. The timer results are each request totally different. Sometimes less then a second and a request later > 30 seconds.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end there was only one solution to get it acceptable fast by a periodic checker which reads all pages into a scripdb database end the search wil look in the scripdb instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have a folder from drive that updates a sites list.  I had to use a while{} finished is false statement, cuz it would  cause the same error sometimes when just trying to update the list. Would that help?

Comment: I have already a solution to get arround this error but it takes way to long. No one will wait for more then 5 seconds for a search to finish. I think the biggest issue is the search it self, even if you specify a single page. `code`var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(siteURL); var result = page.search(json.searchParam1); `code`